SQLAlchemy to join a parent table with a child table where the child needs info from another table
I am building a FastAPI app and struggling to join multiple tables using SQLAlchemy v2 to achieve a particular query output format. I have three models as follows:
class MaterialReceipt(Base, AuditMixins):
    material_receipt_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    pic = Column(String)
    is_visible = Column(Boolean)
    material_receipt_lines = relationship("MaterialReceiptLine", backref='material_receipt')


class MaterialReceiptLine(Base, AuditMixins):
    material_receipt_line_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    material_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("material.material_id"))
    material_receipt_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("material_receipt.material_receipt_id"))
    quantity = Column(Float)
    exp_date = Column(Date)

class Material(Base, AuditMixins):
    material_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    sku = Column(String)
    location = Column(String)
    low_stock_threshold = Column(Float)

Material Receipt is the parent and MaterialReceiptLine child. MaterialReceiptLine is linked to Material via material_id. I want to query all the material receipts and the results should be in the following format:
[
    {
        "material_receipt_id": ...,
        "pic": ...,
        "is_visible": ...
        "material_receipt_lines": [
            {
                "material_receipt_line_id": ...,
                "name": ...,
                "sku": ...,
                "quantity": ...,
                "exp_date": ...
            }, ...
        ]
    }, ...
]

I know that in order to join Material Receipt and Material Receipt Line I can try the following code with sqlalchemy:
        material_receipts = (
            (self.db
             .query(MaterialReceiptModel)
             .join(MaterialReceiptLineModel)
             .options(contains_eager(MaterialReceiptModel.lines))
             )
            .filter(MaterialReceiptModel.is_visible)
            .order_by(MaterialReceiptModel.created_at.desc())
            .all()
        )

However, I don't know how to join Material and Material Receipt Line to achieve the required output format. Is there a way to do it?
Thank you!

Answering your question is not easy because you did not provided all the information needed to answer it or the information you provided is contradictory.
For example:

What database are you using? (Because some options are not available in all database systems)
What are the tables' name in your database? (We have to guess)
what is AuditMixins and is it relevant to your question?
The query you provided seems to reference MaterialReceiptModel, MaterialReceiptLineModel, MaterialReceiptModel. They are not defined anywhere in your example but you have defined MaterialReceipt, MaterialReceiptLine, Material. Are we supposed to guess they are supposed to be the same things?

To summarize, you did not provided us with a minimal reproducible example
We can only guess what you wanted to do. The output you are asking is hierarchical but a query wont be able to get you directly your answer.
So here is what I came up with what I understood from your question:
import random
import string
import datetime
import json

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, ForeignKey, Float, Date, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, sessionmaker

# Defining the classes mapped
Base = declarative_base()

class MaterialReceipt(Base):
    __tablename__ = "material_receipt"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    pic = Column(String)
    is_visible = Column(Boolean)
    material_receipt_lines = relationship("MaterialReceiptLine", backref="material_receipt")

class MaterialReceiptLine(Base):
    __tablename__ = "material_receipt_lines"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    material_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("material.id"))
    material_receipt_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("material_receipt.id"))
    quantity = Column(Float)
    exp_date = Column(Date)
    material = relationship("Material")

class Material(Base):
    __tablename__ = "material"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    sku = Column(String)
    location = Column(String)
    low_stock_threshold = Column(Float)

# Tools used to generate example random data
def generate_random_string():
    return "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=20))

location_examples = (
    "Paris",
    "London",
    "New York",
    "Sydney",
    "Tokyo",
    "Los Angeles",
    "Moscow",
    "Berlin",
    "San Francisco" 
)

amount_of = {
    "receipts": lambda: range(random.randint(2, 4)),
    "materials": lambda: range(random.randint(2, 6))
}

# Creating random objects and saving them to our example database
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)

session = Session()

receipts = (
    MaterialReceipt(
        pic=generate_random_string(),
        is_visible=random.choice((True, False)),
        material_receipt_lines=[
            MaterialReceiptLine(
                quantity=random.uniform(0, 5000),
                exp_date=(datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=random.randint(1, 90))),
                material=Material(
                    name=generate_random_string(),
                    sku=generate_random_string(),
                    location=random.choice(location_examples),
                    low_stock_threshold=random.uniform(10, 20)
                )
            )
            for also_not_used in amount_of["materials"]()
        ]
    )
    for not_used in amount_of["receipts"]()
)

session.add_all(receipts)
session.commit()
session.close()

# The answer is here:

# Retrieving the objects from the database
another_session = Session()

output = [
    {
        "material_receipt_id": receipt.id,
        "pic": receipt.pic,
        "is_visible": receipt.is_visible,
        "material_receipt_lines": [
            {
                "material_receipt_line_id": line.id,
                "name": line.material.name,
                "sku": line.material.sku,
                "quantity": line.quantity,
                "exp_date": line.exp_date.isoformat()
            }
            for line in receipt.material_receipt_lines
        ]
    }
    for receipt 
    in another_session.query(MaterialReceipt).filter(MaterialReceipt.is_visible).all()
]

another_session.close()

# Displaying the output in the format asked
print(json.dumps(output, indent=4))

I have used a in-memory SQLite for this example but things could be different if you are using something else. I have used the fact that by defining relations between objects, I could easily get the linked between MaterialReceipt, MaterialReceiptLine, Materialobjects.
I have to mention that the output you asked for looks a lot like the JSON format so I took advantage of the json python module for the output format. I also took advantage of the fact that since Python 3.7, dictionaries preserves the insertion order so that the output dictionary when transformed in a JSON object has its values in the right order.

However you mentioned that are using SQLAlchemy v2. But the style of your code is considered legacy. You should use more modern SQLAlchemy idioms from now on. You should go look at, at the very least, the SQLAlchemy ORM Quick Start to have an idea of how things should be done.
So this answer would look like:
import datetime
import random
import string
import json

from typing import List

from sqlalchemy import Boolean, ForeignKey, Date, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, Session

# Defining the classes mapped
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class MaterialReceipt(Base):
    __tablename__ = "material_receipt"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    pic: Mapped[str]
    is_visible: Mapped[bool]
    material_receipt_lines: Mapped[List["MaterialReceiptLine"]] = relationship(back_populates="material_receipt", cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        receipt_lines = "\n\t".join(f"{x!r}" for x in self.material_receipt_lines)
        return f"Material(id={self.id!r}, pic={self.pic!r}, is_visible={self.is_visible!r}, material_receipt_lines=[\n\t{receipt_lines}\n])"

class MaterialReceiptLine(Base):
    __tablename__ = "material_receipt_lines"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    material_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("material.id"))
    material_receipt_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("material_receipt.id"))
    quantity: Mapped[float]
    exp_date: Mapped[datetime.date]
    
    material_receipt: Mapped["MaterialReceipt"] = relationship(back_populates="material_receipt_lines")
    material: Mapped["Material"] = relationship()

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"MaterialReceiptLine(id={self.id!r}, quantity={self.quantity!r}, exp_date={self.exp_date!r}, material=\n\t\t{self.material!r})"

class Material(Base):
    __tablename__ = "material"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    sku: Mapped[str]
    location: Mapped[str]
    low_stock_threshold: Mapped[float]

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Material(id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r}, sku={self.sku!r}, location={self.location!r}, low_stock_threshold={self.low_stock_threshold})"

# Tools used to generate example random data
def generate_random_string():
    return "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=20))

location_examples = (
    "Paris",
    "London",
    "New York",
    "Sydney",
    "Tokyo",
    "Los Angeles",
    "Moscow",
    "Berlin",
    "San Francisco" 
)

amount_of = {
    "receipts": lambda: range(random.randint(2, 4)),
    "materials": lambda: range(random.randint(2, 6))
}

# Creating random objects and saving them to our example database
engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    receipts = (
        MaterialReceipt(
            pic=generate_random_string(),
            is_visible=random.choice((True, False)),
            material_receipt_lines=[
                MaterialReceiptLine(
                    quantity=random.uniform(0, 5000),
                    exp_date=(datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=random.randint(1, 90))),
                    material=Material(
                        name=generate_random_string(),
                        sku=generate_random_string(),
                        location=random.choice(location_examples),
                        low_stock_threshold=random.uniform(10, 20)
                    )
                )
                for also_not_used in amount_of["materials"]()
            ]
        )
        for not_used in amount_of["receipts"]()
    )

    session.add_all(receipts)
    session.commit()

# The answer is here:

# Retrieving the objects from the database
with Session(engine) as another_session:
    stmt = select(MaterialReceipt).where(MaterialReceipt.is_visible)

    output = [
        {
            "material_receipt_id": receipt.id,
            "pic": receipt.pic,
            "is_visible": receipt.is_visible,
            "material_receipt_lines": [
                {
                    "material_receipt_line_id": line.id,
                    "name": line.material.name,
                    "sku": line.material.sku,
                    "quantity": line.quantity,
                    "exp_date": line.exp_date.isoformat()
                }
                for line in receipt.material_receipt_lines
            ]
        }
        for receipt in another_session.scalars(stmt)
    ]

# Displaying the output in the format asked
print(json.dumps(output, indent=4))

